# How to use command line (not command line script) to rebuild solution file for windows desktop application

Tags: azure-devops

I am using azure-devops pipeline to build my solution. I have used MS build to rebuild the solution which has 3rd party setup. But it doesn't include all the references.  There is command line script but I need to commands line to rebuild the setup. in TFS it is working for me but for azure pipe line how can I use..?

Comment: Have you [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild)?

Comment: Use nuget restore before the ms build task